# android webviewer doesn't displaying websites correctly

Tags: android

I'm using a webviewer for displaying my website . The websites are in persian . 
The problem is that the contents are really messed up and it displays it very very bad .

Is there anyway to solve this problem ? I've tried too many websites but non of them showed well .

Thanks

Comment: And please elaborate on "really messed up and it displays it very very bad"

Answer (score 0):

```
 WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
        WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        wv.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Add:

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

to your AndroidManifest.xml if you haven't done so. Also check if you have internet connection on your emulator. Try opening the Browser. If you do not have internet connection try to restart the emulator.